# How to set number of copies getPrintParams()

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to add some JS to my pdf creation process to save some time. My goal is to basically click a button generate a PDF and have it print.

Right now I have:
`var pp = this.getPrintParams();
pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.full;
this.print(pp);`

The only problem is that I don't know how to set the number of copies to print. I want pass a variable and print that many copies. The problem is that I can't really find any documentation discusses the methods in this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, this question is old. But I was looking for a solution, too. And I found [here](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Print-button-select-page-print-copies-print-javascript-q126346.aspx), that it should work with the following:

```js
//no of copies
var n = 3;

var pp = this.getPrintParams();

//here is the magic
pp.NumCopies=eval(n);

this.print(pp);
```

For me, this is working with tcpdf and Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var n = 3;
var pp = this.getPrintParams();
pp.NumCopies=eval(n);
this.print({bUI: false,bSilent: true,bShrinkToFit: true,printParams:pp});
```

Answer (score -1):

Not possible, which is a good thing; since otherwise some websites would specify a high number and people who don't expect this would accidentally print lots of pages instead of just a single one.

Comment: It is possible.. pp.NumCopies

Answer (score -2):

You should call print method twice or more times, like the following:

```
this.print({bUI: false,bSilent: true,bShrinkToFit: true});
this.print({bUI: false,bSilent: true,bShrinkToFit: true});
```

I think it's not possible to set the number of copies.

**See also:**

- [Adobe's Print Production documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_Dev_PrintProduction.75.1.html#1516092)