# Set the number of copies to print

Tags: asp.net-mvc, printing

I have an MVC project that prints multiple labels in an order through a browser. Is there anyway to set the number of copies to print? From reading SO [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771741/how-to-set-number-of-copies-getprintparams) it looks like JS is out, so I'm stuck where to go next. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't. See [How to set number of copies getPrintParams()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771741/how-to-set-number-of-copies-getprintparams), [How to set the number of copies to print from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823264/how-to-set-the-number-of-copies-to-print-from-javascript).

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative approach since JS won't work...

Comment: There is no alternative, other than browser plugins. You can't control the number of copies printed from a browser, other than by being the user that does the printing or being a plugin.

Comment: ah gotcha thank you. Have you ever used http://scriptx.meadroid.com/ before? Just wondering if you have any thoughts on it

Comment: I don't know it, but it looks decent and you can download a free trial. It does look to be implemented through a browser plugin, so it'll deliver all the control you're looking for.